# Is there a better way to go about building layouts using ui.router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently using `<div ng-include src="'js/app/partials/layout/header.html'"></div>` just above my `<div ui-view>` in my `index.blade.php` file while using Angular with Laravel.

I have looked into parent state inheritance in `ui.router` but it seems to not work, and feels complicated / or perhaps an overkill for layouts. I just want to inject a header and a footer.

This is what I was doing earlier in my attempt to use ui.router states to create a layout injection system. As you can see below.

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

---

```
.state('root', {
    url: '/',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/header.html'
        }
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: false
    }
})
.state('root.login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    data: {
        requireLogin: false
    }
})
```

Comment: Lets have it for a reference http://plnkr.co/edit/JzERg3aWsJRXN5pjTeYe?p=preview :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your structure of your html, by making named `views` & those will be specified with `templateUrl` & `controller` from `views` option of the state.

Basically inside your home.html you would have three named views such as `header`, `content` & `footer`, root state is setting `header` & `footer` templates with controlllers. Then your child state login will set the content view by using absolute state name using `content@root` in this `@root` because `content` named view has been loaded inside `root` state.

**Markup**

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

**Code**

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/',
      //templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/home.html',//remove this
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/home.html' //add it here
        },
        'header': {
          templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/header.html'
        },
        'footer': {
          templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/header.html'
        }
      },
      data: {
        requireLogin: false
      }
    })

  .state('root.login', {
    url: 'login',
    views: {
      'content@root': {
        templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
      },
    },
    data: {
      requireLogin: false
    }
  })
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5eDBOFV5qbuVKWLyWsor?p=preview)

Comment: Doesn't work. Now the home page on `/` is blank. Didn't load the header.html.

Comment: It's completely blank now. I have ui-view in my index.blade.php.

Comment: @AliGajani I have added `header.html` & `footer.html` so do you have added that templates..any error in console?

Comment: That's the fun part. No error in console. I am loading up the ui-views in index.blade.php. That's the app entry point. Then I have home.html, and header.html where they should be. There is something wrong in the .states that we've up here.

Comment: @AliGajani it should fixed now..adding plunkr soon

Comment: @AliGajani you took me in wrong way, actually I wanted to say that abstract view shouldn't have `/` in in the sense then you child url will become like `login` instead of `/login`, if you define it like `/login` the actual state will be accessible if it has url `\\login` which looks odd and not readable

Comment: @AliGajani It seems working for me.. http://plnkr.co/edit/5eDBOFV5qbuVKWLyWsor?p=preview

Comment: No it didn't. I ended up using ngInclude

Comment: @AliGajani no bro..that would wrong way when you are using `ui-router` as route engine

Comment: @AliGajani I think you are doing some wrong thing..but not able to describe here..? could you explained what you have tried till now?

Answer (score -1):

I Think you use this.

```
`.state('header', {
   abstract : true,
   templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/header.html'

})
.state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/home.html',
            parent : 'header',
            data: {
                requireLogin: false
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            parent : 'header',
            templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            data: {
                requireLogin: false
            }
        })`
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me..what if I have header, footer, nav, side..unscalable

Comment: **header** view parent of all child view directly or indirectly...
`.state('header', {
   abstract : true,
   views : {
     'header' : {
          templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/header.html'
          },
     'footer' : {
           templateUrl :  'js/app/partials/footer.html'
          }
   }
   
})`