# Default views using Angular's $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-router's `$stateProvider` for the routing on an angularjs project and find myself repeating a lot of the same configuration for the route views.

For example:

```
$stateProvider.state('triage', {
    url:       '/operations/triage',
    views: {
        "header": {
            controller:  'CommonCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'common/header.tpl.html'
        },
        "submenu": {
            controller:  'CommonCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'common/submenu.tpl.html'

        },
        "content": {
            controller: 'TriageCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'operations/triage/triage.tpl.html'
        },
        "footer": {
            templateUrl: 'common/footer.tpl.html'
        }
    },
```

The `header`, `submenu` and `footer` will be the same for almost every state, the `content` is really the only part that is variable.

Is there a way to configure the router to always use predefined controllers and templates unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Hope this answer could give an idea about the same http://stackoverflow.com/a/31901331/2435473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here could be called: layout root state. As in detail described here:

- [Angular UI Router - Nested States with multiple layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25667660/1679310)
- [Nested states or views for layout with leftbar in ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310)

One of [the plunkers](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0BJ09BxR7nG9kZDeEIv?p=preview)

we can create a super parent state **`'index'`** or **`'root'`** *(there could be few of them for different state families, e.g. `standard`, `login`, `doc`)* which is creating **unnamed** target for its child/ren (`ui-view=""`) while injecting related templates around:

```
.state('index', {
    abstract: true,
    //url: '/',
    views: {
      '@' : {
        templateUrl: 'layout.html',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
      },
      'top@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.top.html',},
      'left@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.left.html',},
      // this one is unnamed - a target for children
      '@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.main.html',},
    },
  })
```

So, in this example the `layout.html` would look like:

```
<div>

  <section class="left">
      <div ui-view="left"></div>
    </section>

  <section class="right">

    <section class="top">
      <div ui-view="top"></div>
    </section>  

    <section class="main">
      // here is the unnamed view - filled by this state
      // but later target for the child states
      <div ui-view=""></div>
    </section>

  </section>
</div>
```

Now, we can inject that root state into any existing state:

```
.state('client', {
    parent: 'index',
    ...
  })
.state('product', {
    parent: 'index',
    ...
  })
```

so they will have unchanged name ('client', 'product'), i.e. without prefix 'index' or 'root' but will be injected into existing template

The [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/I0BJ09BxR7nG9kZDeEIv?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write our that answer.  Your answer is easier to understand than the accepted answers you linked to.